# Accidentally changed public IP address in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I tried to assign the public IP to another VM by disabling first the IP of VM1 and then using the VM1's public to another VM. But what happened is the IP changed when it was assigned to another VM. How can I revert back the original IP of VM1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you used a dynamic Public IP. If you used a dynamic public IP, unfortunately you are not able to revert it to the original IP address. You are able to do this with a static (or reserved if you are using classic) public IP. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#public-ip-addresses